# How to see if a user has been logged out of the identity server from a Javascript app

Tags: javascript, identityserver4

I have an Identity server 4 application, servral asp .net core applications and a Javascript application.  I have enabled back channel logout on the asp .net core applications.  This way if one of the applications logs out they are all logged out almost instantly.

The issue i am having is with the JavaScript application it will need to poll the identity server every minute to ensure that the user is still logged in.

Example:

User is logged in on Asp .net core app 1, Asp .net core app  2, and Javascript app.  Note these are financial applications a user needs to know that if they log out of one application then they log out of them all when they leave their desk.

They are logged into the identity server which granted each of those applications tokens.   The user then logs out of Asp .net core app 1.  The back channel logout notifies Asp .net core app 2 that the user is now logged out and logs that out as well.

The JavaScript app needs to be logged out as well.  The only way i can think of doing this is by polling the identity server to see if the user has been logged out or not.  If they have then i will need to sign them out of the JavaScript app.

## JavaScript timer

I have created a timer that currently runs every second calling the identity server

```
setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
function myTimer() {
    mgr.getUser().then(function (user) {

        //var url = config.authority + "/connect/userinfo";
        var url = config.authority + "/api/user/LoggedIn";
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        };


        xhttp.open("GET", url);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + user.access_token);
        xhttp.send();
    });

}
```

## Identity server endpoint

I have created an api endpoint on the identity server that checks if the user is authorized.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet("LoggedIn")]
    public IActionResult LoggedIn()
    {
        return Ok(new { IsLoggedIn = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated });
    }
}
```

The problem is because this api endpoint is not loading the user identity.   `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` its coming back as false even when the user is logged in on the identity server.

How check if the user is still logged into the identity server? Is there a better endpoint that will already tell me if the user has an active session and is logged in?  I tried the userinfo endpoint but by passing that a valid access token it just returns true and even when the user has now been logged out.  Isn't there a way to find out if the auth session on the identity server itself from JavaScript?

Comment: What cookie do you want to get? Where do you want to get it? What do you mean with "Is there a better endpoint"?

Comment: I am assuming the cookie set on the identity server for the user.   I had to create my own endpoint on the identity server api/user/loggedin I was wondering if theres an endpoint already set up that will tell if the user is logged in.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought with "Identity Server" you meant your own implementation of one and I just realized, that it is a finished product.

Comment: Maybe you could use JWT as a cookie? It has expiration time, so you'll be logged out when JWT isn't refreshed on server side.

Comment: @AleksejVasinov  The issue is that i need to know the user was logged off the Identity server.   The expire time in the JWT is unimportant. If the user has been logged off the the identity server then they need to be logged out of all of their applications including the javascript application regardless of the JTW expiration time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID Connect has a feature specifically for this purpose:

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

It also happens to be implemented out-of-the-box by `oidc-client-js`. Check out the `monitorSession` property in `UserManagerSettings`

Long story short it polls your identity server *client side* via an iframe that points to the `check_session_iframe` URL and `postMessage` messages. Your IDP maintains a cookie containing the session ID that is accessible from client script and responds depending on if the expected session is still active or not. If it responds with `changed` (i.e. the session is different from what is expected) then your app can respond by attempting a silent reauthentication. If that fails then you can sign the user out and present whatever friendly UI flow you wish.

## example

```
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
mgr.events.addUserSignedOut(function () {
    console.log("user signed out");
    log("user signed out");
});
```

## in action

[image]

Comment: I will check this first thing in the morning!

Comment: It's *fairly* straight forward to implement for applications that use a server-side flow and cookies too. The standard OIDC middleware automatically stores the correct details in the AuthenticationProperties of your auth cookie to enable you to implement the iframe polling stuff on the client side yourself.

Comment: I updated your answer with working code thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You could format response and attach cookie:

```
    HttpResponseMessage response= Request.CreateResponse<CustomResponse>(
        HttpStatusCode.OK,
        new CustomResponse() { IsLoggedIn = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated }
    );

    //create and set cookie in response
    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("IsLoggedIn", User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
    cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
    cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
    cookie.Path = "/";
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
    {
        MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
    };
    response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

    return response;
```

Comment: The problem is that User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is null the api call isnt seeing that the user is logged in.

Comment: In this case, the API controller has to be called via AJAX and act as Proxy. The Bearer authentication passed from AJAX shall be attached to your API controller while making and AUTH check.

Comment: yeah but if the bearer token is called with a valid access token isnt it just going to say that its authorized?   The javascript app may have a valid access token but if the user is no longer logged in on the identity server then they should be logged out of the javascript app.

Comment: The TOKEN shall be invalid when AUTH SESSION is over. The AUTH server shall return 401 or similar.

Comment: The access token is valid for one hour.  During that hour the user has been logged off of the identity server.  If you send a call to the userinfo endpoint with a access token thats still valid it still returns data.   How do i find the Auth session on the identity server then from a Javascript app?  I am trying to find out if the user is logged out on the identity server so that i can log them out of the application.

Comment: Since you have an API endpoint in the middle (between Auth and JS )... it it your authority for JS app. Following this logic, the API controller shall query the identity server every time the JS app is requesting data.

Comment: The api controller is on the identity server again the issue is that User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false.   Its not reporting back the current users session status on the identity server.

Comment: Doesn't make sens what you saying.